# List declaration in the signature file is not being understood correctly in the implementation file

Tags: types, f#

I have the following signature file `F.fsi`:

```
module M =

    type T1 = A | B

    type T2 =
        | F
        | G
        static member x1 : list<T1>
        static member x2 : list<T1>
```

In my implementation file `F.fs` I have the following:

```
module M =

    type T1 = A | B

    type T2 =
        | F
        | G
        static member x1 = [T1.A; T1.B]
        static member x2 = [] // LINE MARKER 1; ERROR OCCURS HERE
```

Visual Studio red-lines the definition of `x2` with the following error message:

> Module 'M' contains `static member M.T2.x2 : obj list` but its signature
>   specifies `static member M.T2.x2 : T1 list`  The types differ

It seems that in the implementation file the empty list is inferred to have a generic type, even though the signature file clearly indicates that the list is of type `T1`.  I attempted the following correction:

```
    static member (x2 : list<T1>) : []
```

But this time I got the following error message:

> Only simple variable patterns can be bound in `let rec` constructs

I have skirted the problem by making `x1` and `x2` into functions instead, but is there a different way to get Visual Studio to infer the type of the list correctly?

Comment: you just experienced a nasty problem: values cannot be generic in .net - so the type-inference (which does not first check your signature file anyway but works top-bottom and left right) sees the `[] : 'a list` and will coerce this to `obj list` because of this ... John already told you how to fix this

Comment: Just a quick comment here: it turns out that `static member x2 : list<T1>` *without the parentheses* also works!  But the parentheses lead to the error indicated in the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The annotation should be

```
module M =

    type T1 = A | B

    type T2 =
        | F
        | G
        static member x1 = [T1.A; T1.B]
        static member x2 : List<T1> = []
```

because you are annotating the return type

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you very much.